# How get the least ID from table after GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to get recent messages of user. And I need get LAST ID of message to each a fetch. How can I do it? Thank you!

**Structure**:
[image]

**Query**:

```
SELECT *
FROM `messages`
WHERE (
  `from` = 1 OR
  `to` = 1
)
GROUP BY (`from` + `to`)
ORDER BY `id` DESC
LIMIT 10
```

**Result**:

[image]

**What I need**?
[image]

If you have same a problem? I find solution!

```
SELECT `id`, `from`, `to`, `text`, `created`
FROM (
  SELECT *, (`from` + `to`) AS `anchor`
  FROM `messages`
  WHERE (
    `from` = 1 OR
    `to` = 1
  )
  ORDER BY `id` DESC
  LIMIT 1
) AS `*`
GROUP BY `anchor`;
```

Comment: After GROUP BY (`from` + `to`) I need get MAX id fro EACH row with limit.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand correctly, you can use a correlated subquery:

```
select m.*
from messages m
where 1 in (m.from, m.to) and
      m.id = (select max(m2.id)
              from messages m2
              where (m2.from = m.from and m2.to = m.to) or
                    (m2.from = m.to and m2.to = m.from)
             );
```

Note:  `from` and `to` are really bad names for columns, because they are SQL keywords.

Comment: Not that. See in the post what i need get there in a picture with result

Comment: @Nick . . . This should return your desired results.  If it doesn't, can you set up a db<>fiddle of some sort?

Comment: Thank my friend! I found a solution! If you are interested it. Then you can look main a post with description my the solution!)))

Comment: @Nick . . . That is not a real solution.  You are using `select *` with `group by`.  First, that will be rejected by most databases, including the more recent versions of MySQL (unless you override the default settings).  Second, there is no guarantee that the row that is returned is the minimum.  This answer should do what you want.